# How to modify JSON in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I use JsonBuilder to build a JSONObject/String.

But, how can I update/change value of one field in this JSONObject/String?

I am not seeing the possibility of doing this using JsonBuilder. What show I use then?

Comment: [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)?

Comment: That will only return a map. Do you mean update the map and convert back to json?

Comment: Yes. JsonSlurper to read the json into a map. Change it, and write the modified map back to json with JsonBuilder

Comment: Yes, that will work. But, I prefer changing the JsonBuilder directly. The JsonBuilder return a map itself. but, that map I can only get the first level properties. For complex properties I am not able to get the value.

Comment: So you want to change the property of a map encoded as a Json String without parsing the String?

Comment: Added an answer that shows how to do it, but it's probably better to get your data right before passing it to JsonBuilder if at all possible (for future proofing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *have* to change the content you already put into the JsonBuilder, then you could do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def map = [ users:[ [ name:'tim', posts:43 ], [ name:'alice', posts:72 ] ] ]

JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder( map )

builder.content.users[ 0 ].name = 'dave'

assert builder.toString() == '{"users":[{"name":"dave","posts":43},{"name":"alice","posts":72}]}'
```

But as `content` is not explicitly exported from the Object, I'd call this a side-effect and would not rely on it working in future versions of Groovy.

Better to get your map right before you pass it to `JsonBuilder`, or if that isn't possible I guess you'll need to parse the Json string with `JsonSlurper` modify the resulting Map and then rebuild the Json with `JsonBuilder` again.