# Changing the labels jsonBuilder creates automatically in Groovy after converting Obj to JSON

Tags: json, groovy, type-conversion, jsonbuilder

I have a class called Case which is like:

```
class Case {
   String caseId;
   Map <String, List<String[]>> listOfCases = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();
}
```

I created several of these cases and add them to a list. Eventually I want to print the list in JSON format in groovy like:

```
for (...){
   // creating many of these cases in a loop and adding to caseList
   caseList.add(myCase);
}
// Finally printing them
println new JsonBuilder( caseList ).toPrettyString()
```

Result looks like this, I chose one only:

```
{
    "caseId": "Case_1",
    "listOfCases": {
        "server-config.xml": [
            [
                "Core",
                "8"
            ]
        ],
        "server-beans.xml": [
            [
                "plugin",
                "mmap"
            ],
            [
                "maxIdle",
                "16"
            ],
            [
                "minIdle",
                "16"
            ],
            [
                "maxCon",
                "16"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I want the listOfCases be replaced with Case_1 so each time I create a new Case with the number incremented, the name follows. Is there anyway to customize the jsonBuilder in groovy to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify a JSON in groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104819/how-to-modify-a-json-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [How to modify JSON in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104819/how-to-modify-a-json-in-groovy) changing the `content` is dangerous, as it attempts to change the original object.  The solution presented there is to send the proper map.

You can prepare a map from your data and pass this like this:

```
class Case {
    String caseId
    Map<String,List<List<String>>> listOfCases
}

def caseList = (1..3).collect{
    new Case(caseId: "Case$it", listOfCases: [ 'abcde': [['1','2'],['4','5']]])
}

println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(caseList.collect{[caseId: it.caseId, "$it.caseId": it.listOfCases]}).toPrettyString()
```

results in

```
[
    {
        "caseId": "Case1",
        "Case1": {
            "abcde": [
    ...
```